# Python 3.6.5 urllib set path

Tags: python, urllib

What I am trying to do is download an image using urllib and save it on the folder of my choice. I have made some progress and found the way to download the image in the same folder as my python script but I can not change the location that the image will be saved.
For example I have the script on the desktop when I run the script it saves the image on the desktop, what I need it to do is instead of saving it in the desktop save it in a folder named images in the desktop.

The code:

```
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

def download_image(url):
    t= datetime.now()
    img_name = str(t.day) + "." + str(t.month) + "." + str(t.year) + " - " + str(t.hour) + "." + str(t.minute) + "." + str(t.second)
    full_name = img_name + ".png"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full_name)

download_image('http://url.com')
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying a full path as second argument to `urlretrieve` instead of only a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the location where you would like to save the file. For example, on a Windows machine `C:\\Users\\hoenie\\`:

```
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

def download_image(url):
    t= datetime.now()
    img_name = str(t.day) + "." + str(t.month) + "." + str(t.year) + " - " + str(t.hour) + "." + str(t.minute) + "." + str(t.second)
    path = 'C:\\Users\\hoenie\\'  # Folder
    full_name = img_name + ".png"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path+full_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just download your image in your python directory and then copy it into the folder of your choice with **shutil.copyfile()** :

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: If OP knew how to specify a `tmp` directory as target, then he could also just specify the final location. Your answer misses the point of the question

Comment: My mistake, I meant to save it into his python directory **as a tmp file** and then copy it wherever he wanted.

Comment: Even worse. The Python directory is for Python itself, not for own programs and data.